# Is there a way to mock a type assertion using gomock?

Tags: go, testing, gomock

i'm new to golang and using `Gomock` for testing. I have generated the mock for the interface `foo`, but in my code theres a piece of logic that uses `foo.(type)`.

May I know if theres a way to mock this and return a type of my choice? If not, what would be a good way to go about doing this? Thanks!

Eg. code snippet:

```
// assume structs A and B implements the interface `foo` 
type foo interface {...}
type A struct {...}
type B struct {...} 

func DoSomething(i foo) {
  // Is there a way to mock this type assertion for i here? 
  switch currentType := i.(type) {
  case *A: 
    ...
  case *B:
    ...
  default:
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share a snippet of the function that implements the logic?

Comment: Sure thing, let me edit the post!

Answer (score 0):

`gomock` generates new implementation for interface. (For interface `Foo` implementation is `MockFoo` struct). In your scenarion such mock will only cover `default` case.

Easiest way to deal with `DoSomething(i foo)` is to pass concrete implementations (testdata based on your scenario)

Comment: Thanks @beam, was wondering if there were other ways other than passing in test data which I guess not. Cheers